# Django - Admin: list_display TextField

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to display the first 10 characters of a `TextField` on a `list_display`.
Is it possible in the admin interface ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can define a callable that returns the first 10 characters of the field, and add that to `list_display`.

More information see the Django docs for [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display).

Comment: What if I want to limit the length in the list view, but I want the admins to be able to edit the field on the item detail view?

Comment: @CsabaToth Adding an item to `list_display` won't affect the item detail view at all. The admins should still be able to edit the field as before.

Answer (score 2):

```
myapp/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.text import Truncator
from django.db import models
from .models import Product

def truncated_name(obj):
    name = "%s" % obj.name
    return Truncator(name).chars(70)

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ['id',  truncated_name, 'category', 'timestamp',]
    list_display_links = [truncated_name]
    list_filter = ['category']

    class Meta:
        model = Product
```

You can also override the fields like so:

```
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.CharField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size': '20'})},
        models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(attrs={'rows': 1, 'cols': 40, 'style': 'height: 1.5em;'})},
}
```